# Expand and collapse on click of link using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I want to expand and collapse list contents when click on links like "more" and "less" using jquery mobile. is it possible? Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try something? Could you share your code?

Comment: Hi Martin, I haven't started to code. Just have an requirement. Basically, when i click on "more" link, the list should expand and vice-versa.

Comment: You should always try to code first before asking. However checkout my answer. You can do this with css only. Best practice is to avoid javascript if possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You should try something by yourself. Use Google for the answer! If you tried for a couple hours and it still don't work, come back again!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I had tried and couldn't find the solutions, so turnedup to stackoverflow. anyways I figured out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi refre this link http://jsfiddle.net/KqFRu/7/

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div class="hiders" style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li>cccc</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div class="hiders" style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li>cccc</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div  class="hiders" style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li>cccc</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div class="hiders" style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li>cccc</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS

```
$('.majorpoints').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.hiders').toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help gayathri..

Comment: if it works fine you can that answer so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Nicest solution is to not use javascript at all. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/zx3du1p6/1/

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;

    &:checked ~ .list-item {
        display: block;
    }
}

.list-item {
    display: none;
}
```

This uses jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/zx3du1p6/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('li').toggleClass('open')
})
```

If you absolutely have to use jquery mobile, you can use the collapsible set: https://jsfiddle.net/zx3du1p6/2/

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Load more</h3>
    <p>List goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want this using jquery mobile :(

Comment: Added jquery mobile to the answer